# Using XDocument to parse element based xml string

Tags: xml, string, linq-to-xml

I have a simple xml string of elements that I'm trying to parse to strings. For example:

```
    <root>
      <element1>one</element1>
      <element2>two</element2>
    </root>"
```

I receive a string like containing elements and their values. It gets assigned to a string variable (such as string sxml).

I'm trying to do the following but all the strings are empty.

```
string sOne = "";
string sTwo = "";

var strings = XDocument.Parse(sxml)
.Decendents("root")
.Select(n => new {
  sOne = n.Element("element1").Value,
  sTwo = n.Element("element2").Value
});
```

Can someone tell me how my syntax should be corrected?

Thanks.

Comment: Your code should work - though you appear to have a typo (`Descendants`, not `Descendents`) - but that may be from posting your code, because it wouldn't compile as posted.

Answer (score 0):

At first, change `Decendents` to `Decendants`.

Then, your `sOne` and `sTwo` string variables cannot be initialized this way.
The LINQ `select new` clause creates an object of an anonymous type as the query result.

Your `strings` variable will hold 1 object of an anonymous type with 2 variables in it.

[image: Anonymous type created with LINQ select new clause]

**In order to initialize your initial strings, you should add these 2 lines below your code:**

```
sOne = strings.ElementAt(0).sOne;
sTwo = strings.ElementAt(0).sTwo;
```